# Weka from Matlab : Attribute Selection

Tags: matlab, attributes, selection, weka

I added the Weka.jar file to my environment variables and can already loadARFF files into Matlab and read the instances. Now I would like to perform batch attribute selection on a set of training and testing pairs of files but I cannot seem to find any tutorials on how to do that from Matlab.

I do not want to do it through weka command line because I have a set of 15 training files, and 15 test files for only one trial (and I have many trials with different ARFF files) hence I wanted to loop through them fast from Matlab.

Your help will be highly appreciated :) thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

First, if you are in the MATLAB Desktop (the MATLAB console) and you preface your command with an exclamation point (!) then you can run command-line arguments. This works in scripts (.m  MATLAB files) too.

Ex:

```
>> !man ls
```

What this means is that the things you can do in a terminal (like from [this tutorial](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Performing+attribute+selection)), you should be able to do in MATLAB.

Second, you can [access Java libraries from MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f44062.html). You can access functions from `weka.attributeSelection` by importing it into your MATLAB workspace and then using the methods you need as you would do in java. For example, here's a .m file written by Matthew Dunham that imports a weka library (`weka.core.converters.ArffLoader`) and uses it in a .m file:

```
function wekaOBJ = loadARFF(filename)
% Load data from a weka .arff file into a java weka Instances object for
% use by weka classes. This can be converted for use in matlab by passing
% wekaOBJ to the weka2matlab function. 
%
% Written by Matthew Dunham

    if(~wekaPathCheck),wekaOBJ = []; return,end
    import weka.core.converters.ArffLoader;
    import java.io.File;

    loader = ArffLoader();
    loader.setFile(File(filename));
    wekaOBJ = loader.getDataSet();
    wekaOBJ.setClassIndex(wekaOBJ.numAttributes -1);
end
```